# BJT vs MOSFET failure modes

Tags: transistors, mosfet, bjt

I know MOSFETs are much more efficient than BJTs in that they don't consume as much power when on whereas a BJT consumes base current the whole time it is on. I also know that MOSFETs tend to fail shorted. I can't find any information on BJT failure modes though/do they usually fail open or closed. Does anyone know about this?

Comment: "bad current" did you mean base current?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, all semiconductors tend to fail shorted unless you put enough current through them to physically blow them apart or fuse the bonding wires. Physically broken packages (eg. diodes) can also result in an open.

Answer (score 2):

To address the first part of your question: It isn't true that MOSFETs are *always* more efficient than BJTs.

In high-current applications, the I<sup>2</sup>R losses in a MOSFET can far exceed the I<sub>C</sub>V<sub>CE(SAT)</sub> losses in a BJT. This is why [IGBT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulated-gate_bipolar_transistor)s are often preferred in high-power equipment.

Comment: ..  in high frequency switching, the gate drive power requirements of a MOSFET can be higher than an equivalent BJT.