# H-bridge with 7815 regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, h-bridge, 7805

[image: this is the schematic with the regulator]

[image]

Could anyone explain to me why my 7815 regulator gets hot and eventually blows up ??

[image: Full H bridge]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! What’s your load current? Do you have any shoot-through in your H-bridge? What does your +15V look like when you start switching? Show oscillograms.

Comment: Iam using a DC motor which draws around 3A

Comment: the configuration works fine but as the speed of the motor increases the 7815 regulator gets hot and blows up, do i need to connect it via a resistor to the low side optocouplers, as the output current of the optos are 2.5A and the regulator is 1.5A

Comment: is any regeneration occuring?  ie is that 24V being increased to 30V, 40V. Also  disconnect the motor and enable it to see if it is just the fact the current rating is too low w.r.t. charging/discharging the gates

Comment: I have disconnected the motor and everything works fine, when i connect the motor is still working fine but the voltage regulator which takes 24V in and gives 15V out blows up, this regulator is powering two nme1515 DC-DC converters and two opto isolators (HCPL-3180) could this be the problem as the isolators have an output current of 2.5A but the 7815 has a max output of 1.5A, maybe is drawing to much current ??

Comment: This is a simple problem of impedance transformation and underestimation of surge current. Surge current is 8 to 10X rated current =W/V determined by winding DCR which is transformed assuming 100% efficiency of DC-DC converter to 24/15^2 across 15v regulator.So your power source is trying to source about 25x the motor rated current.  Next time , do the math.

Comment: how can i resolve this issue

Comment: Choose a proper power supply or use PWM in continuous mode to reduce the load current and raise avg impedance and accelerate slower

Comment: Im using a proper power supply and using PWM with a frequency of 4KHz,

Comment: what is the "++--" box

Comment: NME1515 which is a floating dc-dc converter

Comment: Aside from 2 resistors and the 7815, you have a schematic with 40+ unknown parts.  Why is you ++-- box (NME1515) connected to the motor terminals?  May I suggest you use the sites schematic editor (Ctrl-M) and put a legitimate schematic in with part numbers.  Otherwise this is like pulling teeth and not useful.

Comment: _”the configuration works fine”_ Clearly not. Show full schematic and oscillograms!

Comment: i have added a schematic of half bridge

Comment: Your problem is a fundamentally mistaken design.  Don't use a linear regulator like the 7815 to feed a DC-DC converter **and most definitely do not use it to feed a 3 amp motor!**.

Comment: but is not connected to the motor is fed into the optos and the DC-DC converters ?

Comment: 7815 is a DC regulator, not a converter, or rather it is a downconverter only.  It requires an input voltage greater than 15VDC (typically 17.5VDC but the datasheet says 35VDC) in order to produce a 15VDC output.  It is blowing up because Its maximum current output is only 1A.  I see major problems with the schematic, not sure about the hand drawn one, and there is always the possibility of a mistake in the real world version.  The upper FET? looks like it does nothing except short the 12 V input to ground.

Comment: A 7815 should **not** "blow up" from over current.  It should shut down.  It has current limiting and over heating shutdown.  Something else is killing the 7815.

Comment: sorry my mistake it doesn't atchuly blow up. I ment it gets really out and eventually stops working, the input voltage becomes the same as output (if 24V input than the output is the same).

Comment: Where is your opto burn resistors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must measure or lookup the motor DCR and see if the V+/DCR exceeds the current or power rating of any component cascaded from source to bridge.

Boosting the voltage in a DC-DC converter also boosts the input current load.

*pasted from previous comment...*
Read again until you understand or ask a better question.

This is a simple problem of impedance transformation and underestimation of surge current. Surge current is 8 to 10X rated current =W/V determined by winding DCR which is transformed assuming 100% efficiency of DC-DC converter to 24/15^2 across 15v regulator.So your power source is trying to source about 25x the motor rated current. Next time , do the math

[image]

Comment: but the motor is not connected to the 7815 voltage regulator ?

Comment: Your topology will fail.

Comment: how can i resolve this issue if i want to power the whole thing up from 24V, how should it be connected, I am a student and not sure exactly how to solve this problem

Comment: Define the design requirements with specs.  Logic level inputs. Motor {DCR , Voltage, Power} , Controller functions, RPM vs Torque , feedback? protection for current or torque or thermal limits, shoot-thru prevention  and understand a commercial design before trying to DIY.

Answer (score 2):

You want a regulator, that is specified at a maximum of 1A, to output more than 3A? Furthermore, you want it to dissipate 45W when even under ideal conditions with an infinite heatsink it cannot dissipate more than 20W?

What exactly did you expect would happen?

Your schema makes no sense. Placing a linear regulator to drop the voltage for a switching regulator is just folly. And a step-up switching regulator at that, which actually further increases the power loss that would accrue from just using a linear regulator in the first place. You are simply burning power with no rhyme or reason.

You are already using a switching regulator for your application, choose a different switching regulator that can tolerate your desired input voltage instead.

Comment: Im still not sure what i can do to resolve this as my teacher suggested that I should use a 7815 regulator to power up the NME1515 converter if i want to power it from 24V.

Comment: how can i power up the whole circuit from 24V, from one power source if i want to use the NME1515

Comment: @DanielBashy why? If you paid attention to the answers and comments you would realize that that is not a good choice. If you read the data sheet of the NME1515 itself you would find better choices for your application.

Comment: [The 7815 will **not** explode because the load is too heavy.](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/889348.pdf)  The datasheet says it has current limiting and thermal shutdown.  Something else is going on.

Comment: @JRE it specifies a short-circuit current of ~1A. The designers probably didn't count on it being connected to a negative-resistance load that would actually attempt to increase the current as the output voltage is reduced. This would necessarily lead to a run-away condition with >20W of power dissipation.

Comment: Could you explain this further please

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to strip away some of your details of your circuit, and show you something that will make your 7815 unhappy.

Lets look at your motor with just half of the H-Bridge:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f71sBP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you switch Control1 and Control2 such that current flows (the motor runs,) and then you shut them off, then you will get a voltage spike that goes onto your 24V rail.

Depending on how much current it can **sink**, the voltage on the 24V rail will rise.

If it can sink current well, then the voltage will only go up a little.  Nothing interesting happens.  This would be the case if your 24V comes from a battery with short leads.

If it can't sink current (say, like a typical regulated power supply) then the voltage will rise considerably.  This can get really interesting.

The 7815 has a maximum input voltage of 35V.  The spikes from the motor can easily get that high, and higher.

This can also happen if you are using a battery with long leads.  The long wires form an inductor, and prevent the battery from absorbing the (short, sharp) spikes from switching the motor.

If you repeatedly hit the 7815 with more voltage than it was made for, it will eventually give up and die.

I think this is more likely the reason your 7815 keeps giving out on you.

The 7815 has a limit on output current, and a thermal shutdown so it really can't "burn out" or "blow up."

If you exceed the input ratings, though, then you will kill something inside it.  I expect the pass transistor is giving out.

---

You say that the 15V output starts to deliver the full 24V.  That would fit with the pass transistor failing shorted.  [Transistors tend to fail short](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102960/bjt-vs-mosfet-failure-modes) as long as they aren't carrying enough current to burn/melt/explode.

So, how do you confirm and fix this?

Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fID4rx.png)</sup>

Add R1 and D1.  If that fixes the problem, then the voltage spikes were the cause.

D1 clips the voltage to something the 7815 can handle.  R1 limits the current so that D1 doesn't burn out.

You'll need to size R1 such that you get enough current for your DC/DC converters to operate, but that D1 doesn't have to handle too much current when the voltage spike hits.

R1 will need to be rated for enough power to run you DC/DC converters continuously.

That really shouldn't be that much power, though.  You aren't really doing much with the output of the DC/DC converters.  They are only there to power the opto-couplers and drive the FET gates.

Comment: hi thank you so much for this useful information, basically what exactly happens is that as i increase the PWM the 7815 regulator gets very hot and if i check the output from it is almost the same as the input ( if i apply 24V input then i will get the same on the output). I am wondering if maybe also there could be a problem with the optos drawing to much current as they have a output peak current of 2.5A on every rising edge ???

Comment: The information in that comment belongs in the question.  Does the output of the 7815 stay high?  You crank up the PWM, the output voltage of the 7815 goes up to 24V.  Does it then stay at 24 V when you lower the PWM, or does it go back down to 15V?

Comment: no it stays at 24V even if i put it at 0% duty cycle the output will stay at the same as the input, i have tried to use the supply voltage at 18V swell but the same thing happens again, after a short period of time as i increase the PWM than the regulator gives up i think

Comment: OK.  That's it.  You really are killing the 7815.  If you have a scope, you could check the 24V rail (right at the 7815 input) and see what it looks like when the motor is running.  Stay at low PWM so as not to kill the 7815.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help i will check this out when i go back to uni as i don't have the facilities to do it at home, is this why it gets really hot as well do you know ??

Comment: could the opto be drawing to much current from the regulator ?

Comment: As I have mentioned **several** times, the 7815 will shutdown if it gets too hot, and has current limiting - you **cannot** kill it by drawing too much current because it won't allow you to draw too much current.

Comment: ok, thank you for your help, if i still have the same problem after i have checked what you have advised me to do, is there anything else can do to resolve the issue or could it be something else